# VSCode Type Hint toggle display

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I toggle on and off the display of Type hints in VS Code? For example, I've got the code `.remoteOf(ClassServiceClient.class)` and what I see is `.remoteOf(CLAZZ:ClassServiceClient.class)` but I can't actually select or seem to interact with the CLAZZ word.

How do I toggle this on and off? It seems useful in certain situations, but it just makes me think I typoed something.

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I haven't been able to come up with a word that seems to describe this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called `Inlay Hints` and can be found under the Editor section.

After this, I've gone from displaying `clazz:@Log4J2` to `@Log4J2`, and have enabled the option to display this hint by holding down a set of keys, ctrl + alt by default on Windows.